# Best hosting provider

Tags: web-hosting

What is the best hosting service available to host a website which has 1000 of videos?

Note: Users will upload videos directly onto my site. I wont embed any videos from youtube, etc

Kindly let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afrida that this question isn't really programming related, and will likely be closed.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Serverfault maybe, perhaps even SuperUser. Certainly not SO.

Comment: "best" by what criteria? cost, uptime, manageability, location?

Comment: Why don't the people at stackoverflow start migrating these to webmasters instead?

Answer (score 2):

YouTube or Vimeo

If you want the actual website hosted externally, then just upload to said services and embed the videos on your site

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. 

I need a solution, if users upload videos directly onto my site.

Answer (score 0):

Your stated requirements are extremely vague so expect to get only extremely vague replies.

Having said that, look into Amazon EC2 and [CloudFront Streaming](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2009/12/15/announcing-cloudfront-streaming/).